# Unable to pass recordId to Screen flow component on Community Record Detail Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, experience-cloud, community-cloud, flow-screen-component

Thanks in advance for helping!

I have an LWC that displays the flows conditionally using a LWC based on field value on a record page. I am able to apply the conditional visibility using custom LWC component but I cannot pass the recordId to the screen flows.

**LWC:**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import LEAD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';
import LEAD_STATUS from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Lead_Accepted__c';
import LEAD_RECORD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Id';


const leadFields = [LEAD_STATUS];

export default class ConditionalRender extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api lead;
    @track LEAD_OPEN;
    @track LEAD_OBJECT;
    @track LEAD_STATUS;
    @track LEAD_RECORD;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : '$recordId', fields: leadFields}) lead;
    get isOrg() {
        let status = getFieldValue(this.lead.data, LEAD_STATUS);
        if (status==='Yes'){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
      }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" title="Lead Outcome">
        <template if:true={isOrg}>
            <div>
                <lightning-flow flow-api-name="Lead_Outcome_Status"></lightning-flow>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:false={isOrg}>
            <div>
                <lightning-flow flow-api-name="Lead_Acceptance_Status"></lightning-flow>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Lead</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID"
                description="Should be set to {!recordId}" default="{!recordId}" />
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID"
                description="Should be set to {!recordId}" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: How are you trying to pass the recordId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass in the parameters:

```
<lightning-flow
    flow-api-name="Lead_Outcome_Status"
    flow-input-variables={inputVariables}>
</lightning-flow>
```

Where `inputVariables` is defined as:

```
get inputVariables() {
  return [ {
    name: "RecordId",
    type: "String",
    value: this.recordId
  } ];
}
```

Note that you could have also used a merge field with `flow-api-name` to eliminate the entire for the `if:true`/`if:false` duplication:

```
get flowName() {
  // Beware of ASI if you use ternary operator like this
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion
  return (
    getFieldValue(this.lead.data, LEAD_STATUS) === "Yes" 
      ? "Lead_Outcome_Status"
      : "Lead_Acceptance_Status"
  );
}
```

```
<div lwc:if={lead.data}>
  <lightning-flow
    flow-api-name={flowName}
    flow-input-variables={inputVariables}>
  </lightning-flow>
</div>
```

Note that `if:true` and `if:else` are deprecated. Use `lwc:if`, `lwc:elseif`, and `lwc:else` instead. Read more in [Render HTML Conditionally](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I found the parameter for input variables when I did some more research but using the merge field is pretty good solution as well. Will try that out. And also thanks for sharing the info about if:true.